# The named strategy can't work for spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My DB column is like user_id,but the entity is userId.I don't want to @column annotations.And I want to used named stratrgy to configure that.

The configure on application.xml and persistence.xml like below:

application.xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceForCCP" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:/persistenceForCCP.xml" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceForCCP" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
          <!--   <prop key="spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit.strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl</prop> -->

           <prop key=" hibernate.physical_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
               <!--  <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop> -->

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


persistence.xml like below


   <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_statement"/>
```

but the message like below

Hibernate:

```
select
    couriercom0_.id as id1_0_,
    couriercom0_.billNoProvider as billNoPr2_0_,
    couriercom0_.createDateGMT as createDa3_0_,
    couriercom0_.createDateLoc as createDa4_0_,
    couriercom0_.createDateLocTz as createDa5_0_,
    couriercom0_.isActive as isActive6_0_,
    couriercom0_.name as name7_0_,
    couriercom0_.timestamp as timestam8_0_ 
from
    courier_company couriercom0_
```

> 2017-11-24 15:05:51 860 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:129 [:] - SQL Error:
>   1054, SQLState: 42S22

Comment: The persistence.xml like below

Comment: What is the question? Why do you configure the NamingStrategy twice? Always include full stack traces

Comment: There is no user_id the query